# Inequality involving nested absolute values

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, absolute-value, elementary-functions

I don't understand where I'm wrong in my reasoning about this inequality:
$$\big\vert x - \vert 1-x\vert\big\vert < 1$$
**Attempts**
$$\vert 1-x\vert =
\begin{cases} 1-x & \text{if}\quad x\leq 1 \\  x-1 & \text{if}\quad x > 1 \end{cases}$$
So then I have
$$\begin{cases} \vert x - (1-x)\vert < 1 & \text{if}\quad x\leq 1 \\
\vert x - (x-1)\vert < 1& \text{if}\quad x>1 \end{cases}$$
But the second one is false, since it reads $\vert 1 \vert < 1$, and the first one reduces to
$$\vert 2x - 1 \vert < 1$$
Here again I have two cases
$$\begin{cases} 2x-1 < 1 & \text{if}\quad  x \geq 1/2 \\
1-2x < 1 & \text{if}\quad  x < 1/2 \end{cases}$$
with the condition above of $x \leq 1$. The solution of this is $x \geq 1/2$, hence the final solution reads $x \in\left[\frac12, 1\right]$.

Yet the solution should be $-1 < x < 1$ or $1 < x < 3$.

I don't get it.

Here is what Mathematica says:

[image]

Comment: Following *“So then I have”* the same inequality is displayed twice. The solution of $2x-1 < 1$ is not $x \ge 1/2$.

Comment: What did you enter into Mathematica? The blue line is definitely not the graph of $\vert x - \vert 1-x\vert \vert$.

Comment: Wolfram Alpha seems to give a [sensible graph](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=abs%28x-abs%281-x%29%29)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$x< 1$ and $|2x-1|<1$. You cannot drop the absolute value sign here. Now consider the cases $2x-1>0$ and $2x-1 \le 0$.

[$-1 < x < 1$ or $1 < x < 3$ is also not the correct answer. For example, $x=2$ is surely not a solution].

Comment: Thank you, yet Mathematica displays a plot in which $x = 2$ seems legit...

Comment: I Think it's a bug perhaps, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

"and the first one reduces to" I think you miss that the inequality you're considering is
$$|2x-1|<1$$
Here you can go solving with
$$-1<2x-1<1\\
0<2x<2\\
0<x<1$$
Hence the solution is $x\in (0,1)$

Answer (score 0):

*Your attempt works,* it is only on the very last yard, or metre, after the last case distinction, where you fail:
The second row $\,1-2x < 1\,\land\, x <\frac12\,$ and the first row
$\,2x-1 < 1\,\land\, x\geq\frac12\,$ yield
$\,0<x<\frac12\,$ and $\,\frac12 \leqslant x < 1$, respectively, whence any $\,0<x<1\,$ fulfils the inequality.

*Your attempt starts* by resolving the inner absolute value first.
Alternatively peel the onion, i.e., first resolve the exterior one to obtain
$$\begin{align}-1 & \;<\; x-|1-x| \;<\; 1\qquad\big|-x\quad\big|\cdot(-1)\\[2ex]
\implies\quad x- 1 &  \;<\; |1-x| \;<\; x+1
\end{align}$$
The first "$<$" yields $\,x-1<0\iff x<1$. By the second "$<$" you then get $\,1-x<x+1\iff 0<x$. And all is resumed by $\,x\in (0,1)\,$.